# firefox hidden proxy login screen

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, proxy

I have a very stupid problem with Firefox and the proxy authentication. We are on Kubuntu 18.04 and Firefox Quantum 60.0.1

I had configured the proxy settings trough the /etc/environment config file and it does work fine.

The only problem is, when I launch firefox, the proxy login screen is hidden behind the main firefox window. This is not a great problem but, since we want to deploy Kubuntu as the default OS for our company, it will bother the users.

Is it a way to change the behavior and have the login screen in front of the main firefox window ?

Or better, is it possible to do some proxy autologin as we do in MS Windows ?

Thanks,

Comment: It seems that nobody know the solution. So we took an alternative. Instead of setting the system proxy, we use the lockPref settings of Firefox to set up the proxy via a proxy.pac.